# Shiny Dashboard: Adding objects to input list without clicking on sidebar tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I have a `shiny` app in `R` that uses the `shinydashboard` package to create a dashboard with three tabs in the sidebar. The first two tabs each display a table (created with `rhandsontable`). The third tab also displays a table, but it is computed from the tables in tabs 1 and 2. The simple example below works if you click on tab 1 and tab 2 before clicking on tab 3. If you launch the app and click on tab 3 directly (i.e. skipping tab 2), the app will crash because `Table2` has not been added to the `input` list.

Is there a way to add `Table2` to the `input` list without having to click on tab 2?

PS: I am aware that, in the simple example below, there are other ways of getting the desired output. My question is specifically about the timing of when objects get added to the `input` list, and if/how I might be able to alter this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
        
        dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = 'tabs',
                                     menuItem("Tab1", tabName = 'Tab1'),
                                     menuItem("Tab2", tabName = 'Tab2'),
                                     menuItem("Tab3", tabName = 'Tab3'))), 
        
        dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "Tab1", rHandsontableOutput("Table1")),
                               tabItem(tabName = "Tab2", rHandsontableOutput("Table2")),
                               tabItem(tabName = "Tab3", rHandsontableOutput("Table3"))))
      )
    ),

  server = function(input, output){
    
    output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10))))
    output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10))))
    
    observeEvent(input$tabs, {
      if(input$tabs=="Tab3"){
        print(names(input)) # only contains Table2 if I click on its tab in the sidebar
        table1 <- hot_to_r(input$Table1)
        table2 <- hot_to_r(input$Table2) # fails if I have not clicked on Tab2
        output$Table3 <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(table1+table2))
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: usually you can around such issues with `outputOptions(output, "Table2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`, but here it does something funky with your "Table2", I'm not sure why (but your "Table3" works now...)

Comment: @starja: This does the trick - thanks! I'm also not sure why Table2 looks weird, but I suspect it has something to do with rhandsontable. If you click on one of the cells, the rest of the table displays correctly.